# bash - excluding directory in "for file in $(find ...)"

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, find, backup

I have to do a script, which copy all the *.txt files from home directory to the newly created directory specified in the first argument of this script (${1}).

If the backup directory already exists, I want to skip it. I was trying the -prune excluding in find, but it doesn't work for me. Finally I have made if statement in the loop, which also doesn't work, and I don't know why...Thank's for help!!

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir ${1}

for file in $(find ~/ -name *.txt)

do

    if [ ! -f ~/${1}/$file ]
    then
        cp -i -v $file -t ~/${1}
    fi

done
```

Comment: "doesn't work for me" ... Uh, okay. How?

Comment: If you don't need directory recursion, `cp *.txt destination/`, maybe with `cp -n`. See also `rsync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the code, You are creating the directory:

```
mkdir ${1}
```

But copying and testing a different path (`-f ~/${1}/$file`, `-t ~/${1}`). Create a variable to prevent such errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
dest=~/${1}
[ -d "$dest" ] || mkdir "$dest"
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for file in $(find ~/ -name '*.txt' -print)
do
  dfile="$dest/"$(basename "$file")
  if [ "$file" -ef "$dfile" ]; then
    echo same
  else
    cp -i -v "$file" -t "$dfile"
  fi  
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: Breaks as soon as a file has a space in its name. Also, it's a bit clumsy with absolute/relative paths.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but cp is still trying to copy files from $dest path to $dest path...

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -n "$1" ]] || { echo >&2 'Give me an argument!'; exit 1; }

destdir=$(readlink -m -- "$1")

[[ "$destdir" == *\** ]] && { echo >&2 "Sorry, I'm in the stupid situation where the destination dir contains the \`*' character. I can't handle this."; exit 1; }

mkdir -pv -- "$destdir" || { echo >&2 "Couldn't create directory \`$destdir'. Sorry."; exit 1; }

find "$HOME" -path "$destdir" -prune -o \( -name '*.txt' -exec cp -iv -t "$destdir" -- {} \; \)
```

Pro: Works with files that have spaces or funny symbols in their name (unlike yours) (except one stupid case, see *Con* below).

Con: As ormaaj pointed out in a comment, this might fail miserably if the name of your destination path contains the pattern character `*`. This case is safely taken into account, and the script exits gracefully if it ever happens.

**Explanations.**

- Give an argument to that script. It can be absolute of relative to the current directory. `readlink`, with the `-m` option will take care to translate this to an absolute path: that's the variable `destdir`.
- The directory `$destdir` is created with its parents, if applicable.
- In home directory, if we find `$destdir` directory, we prune this branch, otherwise, we look for all `*.txt` files and copy them to `$destdir`.

Once again, this script is 100% safe regarding file names with funny symbols: spaces, newline characters or hyphens, except for the pattern character `*` in the destination directory name, but that case is handled safely by a graceful exit, instead of potentially screwing up the files.

Comment: It isn't safe when destdir contains pattern characters. Generally, `-path` and `-prune` don't mix. Unlike globs, `-path` doesn't evaluate each path component separately. e.g. `/foo/*/bork` matches both `/foo/bar/bork` and `/foo/bar/baz/bork`.

Comment: @ormaaj You're right! I forgot the stupid pattern character `*`. Now why do you say `-path` and `-prune` don't mix? There's a nice example about using them together in `man find`.

Comment: bleh right, I misread that as "use -name instead of -path". This is pretty close though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this to

```
mkdir -p "$1"
find ~/ -name "$1" -prune , -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 cp -n -v -t "$1"
```

You must quote `*.txt`, otherwise the shell will expand it to all `.txt` files in the current directory instead of searching for all `.txt` files below your home directory. `-name "$1" -prune` excludes the backup directory.

[`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) calls [`cp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) with as many filenames as possible and so saves a lot of time.

`cp -n` instead of `cp -i` prevents overwriting files, which already exist. If you want to keep it, you might replace `-n` by `-i` of course.

If you want to retain the directory hierarchy, [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) might be better suited for this backup task.